# The instrumentation test apk either has no tests or the runner after adding room testing

Tags: android, android-testing, android-room

I followed Florina Muntenescu`s [article about room migration tests](https://medium.com/google-developers/testing-room-migrations-be93cdb0d975) and after adding room testing in my gradle file I started to have this error when running my UI tests:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"br.com.jonathanzanella.TestRunner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", 
zip file "/data/app/br.com.jonathanzanella.myexpenses.debug.test-1/base.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/br.com.jonathanzanella.myexpenses.debug-1/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/br.com.jonathanzanella.myexpenses.debug.test-1/lib/x86, /data/app/br.com.jonathanzanella.myexpenses.debug-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I am using room and lifecycle observables from architecture components:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$roomVersion"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$roomVersion"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$roomVersion"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"
```

roomVersion is 1.0.0

I have a custom test runner:

```
testInstrumentationRunner 'br.com.jonathanzanella.TestRunner'
```

The TestRunner class is defined inside androidTest folder.

Looking [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android/issues/51) in facebook screenshot tests makes me think that the problem is that room testing also defines a customRunner and I need to override it as showed in the issue solution, but the code

```
project.app.customTestRunner = true
```

Doesn't compile for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging here at stack overflow I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578381/classnotfoundexception-on-custom-androidjunitrunner) that made my think that the error could be something else.

Since room has a compiler that I need to add to kapt, I tried to add it as a dependency of kapt in androidTest was well and it fixed the problem.

The code that solved the issue is this:

```
kaptAndroidTest "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"
```